# Passing multiple cookies to puppeteer

Tags: json, node.js, cookies, puppeteer

By doing what user Md. Abu Taher suggested, i used a plugin called EditThisCookie to download the cookies from my browser.

The exported cookies are in JSON format, in fact it is an array of objects.

Is it possible to pass this array as a parameter to puppeteer? Can i pass an array of objects to page.setCookies() function?

Comment: There is only [page.setCookie](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies) method which allows setting only one cookie at a time.

Comment: But it contains a rest and spread operator so i think you can pass an array of cookies.

Comment: Fair enough, my bad. [Looking at the code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/32f4c173c818a023d8ae24ecde78c5f3fc57a0c1/lib/Page.js#L345) it can indeed accept an array of objects. So I guess you just need to make sure your saved cookies conform to the [Chrome cookie specs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#type-CookieParam)

Comment: What if the cookies i want to pass does not conform to these specs? I found some cookies that have attributes like (domain, hostOnly, session, storeId, id) that are not in the specs. Also sameSite is "no_restriction" while puppeteer wants 'Strict' or 'Lax'.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use **[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** `await page.setCookie(...cookies);`, where `cookies` is an array of cookie objects.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies

Try it on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const url = 'https://example.com';
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

const cookies = [{
  'name': 'cookie1',
  'value': 'val1'
},{
  'name': 'cookie2',
  'value': 'val2'
},{
  'name': 'cookie3',
  'value': 'val3'
}];

await page.setCookie(...cookies);
const cookiesSet = await page.cookies(url);
console.log(JSON.stringify(cookiesSet));
await browser.close();
```

Comment: Did you try it on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/? `async` wrapper with puppeteer is already provided there.

Comment: Also `page.cookies()` is for reading cookies from specific `url` https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls, `page.setCookie(...cookies)` is for setting cookies.

Comment: @lima_fil you need to add the domain or ULR value in your array for your answer to work: const cookies = [{
   name: 'cookie1',
   value: 'val1',
   domain: '.domain1'
},{
   name: 'cookie2',
   value: 'val2',
   domain: '.domain2'
},{
   name: 'cookie3',
   value: 'val3',
   domain: '.domain3'
}];

Answer (score 23):

You can call `page.setCookie()` with a spread operator to set multiple cookies at once.

However, make sure you call it *before* calling `page.goto(url)` because if you call it afterwards, the cookies will be set after the page has been loaded.

Calling `page.setCookie()` before `page.goto(url)` will require you to add a `domain` key to each cookie.

```js
const cookies = [
  {name: 'cookie1', value: 'val1', domain: 'example.com'},
  {name: 'cookie2', value: 'val2', domain: 'example.com'},
  {name: 'cookie3', value: 'val3', domain: 'example.com'},
];

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setCookie(...cookies);
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await browser.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

[StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension provides support for exporting cookies directly in **Puppeteer** format which conforms to the [Chrome cookie specs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-CookieParam).You can configure it in settings as below:

[image]

Then copy cookies to clipboard:

[image]